# How to integrate BOT framework in a CMS based website for answering FAQ's which questions should be fetched from Backend

Tags: mysql, botframework, umbraco

I am planning to develop a website in Umbraco where FAQ's should be integrated with BOT framework. All the Questions need to be in the backend (MySQL) from there i need to fetch from answering FAQ's. Can anyone please help me out on integrating a BOT framework in a Umbraco based website? Your help in this query is much appreciated

Comment: Thank you so much Jon for sharing this

Answer (score 0):

the way you build this within Umrbaco is going to be very similar to the way you build a BOT framework in a normal language.  YOu could build a FAQ document-type within Umbraco and put all the questions within the CMS if you anted.  You could then create a JSON API to render that data to be used by the BOT framework:

https://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-8-tutorials/umbraco-8-tutorials/how-to-create-a-json-api-within-umbraco-8/

If you do not need the data to be edited within Umbraco then you can jsut follow a normal .NET workflow